# Reversing the order of a Fortran linked-list from gen_ll.f90

Tags: linked-list, fortran

I've recently adopted the use of linked lists in Fortran and after some reading decided to use the [gen_ll.f90 package](http://fortran.com/gen_ll.f90) from the [Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Linked+list) which seemed simple and sufficient to my needs.

It was only later that I realized that I must reverse the order of the terms in the list (i.e. 1->2->3->...->N->NULL needs to be N->...->3->2->1->NULL).
I was trying to generate a function which replaces the pointers %P%Next to the previous instead of the next. The logic seemed good, but I keep messing it up somehow.
I would ask for your help with coding this small function.
The source code is attached in the [gen_ll.f90](http://fortran.com/gen_ll.f90) link and the function/subroutine is straight-forward.

This is a sample source code, one of several attempts that I made.
Not sure if this is even correct, as I got to the point of trail-and-error approach just to make sense at the moment, so this might be complete nonsense.

```
SUBROUTINE LI_Flip_Direction(List)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE(List_Type),INTENT(INOUT),TARGET :: List
  TYPE(Link_Ptr_Type) :: Prev,Curr,Next

  Curr%P => List%Head%Next
  Next%P => Curr%P%Next
  NULLIFY(Prev%P)

  ! Loop:
  DO WHILE (ASSOCIATED(Next%P))
     Next%P => Curr%P%Next
     Curr%P%Next => Prev%P
     Prev%P => Curr%P
     Curr%P => Next%P
  ENDDO

  ! Reached the new HEAD:
  List%Head%Next => Curr%P

  RETURN

END SUBROUTINE LI_Flip_Direction
```

Comment: It is Fortran, not FORTRAN.  There were no pointers in the old FORTRAN. Pointers are hard. I am not able to teach them to my students. Only a small number of them is ever able to write a simple linked list.

Comment: We need you to describe your problems. Does your code compile? Does it run? Are there any error messsges? Are the results wong? How wrong? You must describe the problems you have with the code. Do you use all compiler checks?

Comment: @VladimirF the code is fully enclosed in the gen_ll.f90 package link.
The problem to solve is reversing the order of an existing linked list (as mentioned in the question), given by the same code.
I have actually found the issue and will publish an answer

Comment: I wa asking for error messages or output of your subroutine, not the code. The description of the actual problem is not just what the code is supposed to do but telling what is wrong.

Comment: @VladimirF there were no error messages, it just did not provide the requested result and I was asking "why?". However, I have found the answer and provided the corrected code (1 line that was missing to make it work). I don't see why people keep downvote this, especially as I have provided a solution and I cannot erase it (if you claim it is a bad question)

Comment: In that case you should show the wrong values and explain how the correct output should look like. Note that I did NOT downvote the question so at least two other people found the question not good enough. This is a suggestion for you to help you to write better questions.

Comment: I did not at all suggest you have. But if this is a "bad question" (which I don't mind agreeing to), why am I not allowed to remove it? It is either useful (then keep) or not useful (then remove)

Comment: Because there is an accepted answer and the system does not allow deleting questions with accepted answers. You can try unaccepting and deleting your answer first. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make use of the functions which are available in the presented source code. Since you try to revert a linked list which is mono-directional, the best is the retrieve the head and add it to the head of a new linked list. So you could do something like :

```
subroutine LI_Flip_Direction(list)
  implicit none
  type(List_Type),intent(inout) :: list
  type(List_Type)               :: tmp
  type(Link_Ptr_Type)           :: link

  call LI_Init_List(tmp)
  do while(associated(list%Head%Next))
     link = LI_Remove_Head(list)
     call LI_Add_To_Head(link,tmp)
  end do
  if (associated(tmp%Head%Next)) list%Head%Next => tmp%Head%Next
  nullify(tmp%Head%Next)
end subroutine LI_Flip_Direction
```

Take into account that everything here depends on a good implementation of the used code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for a subroutine that reversed the order of an existing list using the linked "library" (gen_ll.f90), for your usage:

```
SUBROUTINE LI_Flip_Direction(List)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE(List_Type),INTENT(INOUT),TARGET :: List
  TYPE(Link_Ptr_Type) :: Prev,Curr,Next

  Curr%P => List%Head%Next
  NULLIFY(Prev%P)

  ! Loop:
  DO WHILE (ASSOCIATED(Curr%P))
   Next%P => Curr%P%Next
   Curr%P%Next => Prev%P
   Prev%P => Curr%P
   Curr%P => Next%P
  ENDDO

  ! Reached the new HEAD:
  List%Head%Next => Prev%P

  RETURN

END SUBROUTINE LI_Flip_Direction
```

Comment: Note that I did no downvoting here, but I can see why someone downvoted. It is not clear at all what you changed and what was wrong with the cide in the question so bothe the question and the answer are almost useless, because this site is not a software repository.